# How to view source code of canvas element

Tags: html, html5-canvas

I am trying to access the source code inside the canvas tag. Is it possible to get source code inside canvas tag?

Answer (score 3):

You cannot get the source code from canvas element . You need to check the javascript to see what's going on in the canvas . Canvas is similar to board where you can draw anything with javascript .

> The canvas element is part of HTML5 and allows for dynamic, scriptable
>   rendering of 2D shapes and bitmap images. It is a low level,
>   procedural model that updates a bitmap and does not have a built-in
>   scene graph

Answer (score 1):

If you use Chrome you're in luck. It has an experimental feature for inspecting Canvas elements. So you can actually profile the canvas element and see step by step each call, and see a shot of the output of that call.

In chrome type chrome://flags/ into the URL and once the page loads, find "Enable Developer Tools experiments". Close out of Chrome and once you load it back up, in the inspector you will find a new option under Profiles for "Capture Canvas Frame". Run that and it will output a list of every call performed.

I learned about this through twitter and the following link, enjoy.

http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/canvas/inspection/